# jQuery Validator invalid input fields disappear after successful submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Going to keep it short. I have a form that is set to show invalid / incomplete forms after submit. I'm using validate.js and form.js. After submitting an incomplete form, the fields are shown as invalid (correct). Correcting it and resubmitting it successfully processes the form, but the input fields disappear. **I have narrowed down the problem. It's after the code. I guess I need help with that actually.**

```
    $(function() {
$('#fltm_register').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        $('#fltm_register').validate({    
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) { },
                rules: {
                first_name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                last_name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4,
                    email: true
                },
                city: {
                    required: true
                },
                state: {
                    required: true
                },
                zip: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4
                },
                country: {
                    required: true
                }
            },

            messages: {
                first_name: {
                    required: "",
                    minlength: ""
                },
                last_name: {
                    required: "",
                    minlength: ""
                },
                email: {
                    required: "",
                    minlength: "",
                    email: ""
                },
                city: {
                    required: ""
                },
                state: {
                    required: ""
                },
                zip: {
                    required: "",
                    minlength: ""
                },
                country: {
                    required: ""
                }
            },

            invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
                var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                if (errors) {
                    var message = errors == 1
                    ? '<div class="alert alert-block alert-error">You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted below.</div>'
                    : '<div class="alert alert-block alert-error">You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted below.</div>';
                    $(".form_notifications").html(message);
                    $(".form_notifications").fadeIn();
                }
            },
            errorClass:'control-group error',
            errorElement: 'div.control-group',
            highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                $(element).parents("div.control-group").addClass(errorClass); 
            }
        });
        return $('#fltm_register').valid();
    },
    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        $(".form_notifications").hide();
        $(".form_notifications").html(responseText).hide().fadeIn();
        $("#fltm_register")[0].reset();
    }
    /* unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
            $(element).parents(".error").removeClass(errorClass); 
    } */
});
});
```

I have narrowed down the issue. It has to do with:

```
    errorClass:'control-group error',
    errorElement: 'div.control-group',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).parents("div.control-group").addClass(errorClass); 
    }
```

So I need the below code but I don't know exactly where to put it, as it seems to break the AJAX?

```
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
        $(element).parents(".error").removeClass(errorClass); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
errorClass:'control-group error',
errorElement: 'div.control-group',
highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).parents("div.control-group").addClass(errorClass); 
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
    $(element).parents(".error").removeClass(errorClass); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't understand how this worked. However, my code did change significantly from what the original script was, so I should've tried this again. The only thing with this is that it seems to only work for up to 3 control elements? Whereas the ones highlighted are such: <div class="control-group"><div class="controls"><input></div></div>, I do have one that is <div class="control-group"><div class="controls controls-row"><input></div></div> that doesn't highlight with the rest. I'll try to see what I can do about this though...

Comment: Actually sorry, I do have to backtrack on this answer (I think?). While it does seem to fix the submission problem, it started a new one. When I do submit invalid fields, submitting it again without changing anything causes the fields to disappear...

Comment: Yeah it's setting display: none;

Comment: `unhighlight`, is a part method of `.validate()`. So you just only put that within `.validate()` to see the effect.
Could you show me on fiddle?

Comment: It'll be hard to recreate it in fiddle due to styling. How about this (a live example)? [http://fltm.org](http://fltm.org) It's the form after the break.

Answer (score 0):

If unhighlight is a defined method   ,

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).parents("div.control-group").addClass(errorClass); 
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
    $(element).parents(errorClass).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass); 
}
```

Comment: That method still causes the input fields to disappear unfortunately.